# How can I limit tab order to only the controls within a form/div?

Tags: html

I want to replicate the effect that this dialog shows:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

On this page, if you click on "Create new user", it pops a form with some controls. The effect I want to replicate is that when you tab around in this dialog, the tab order cycles only within the controls on that tab, and never to the controls and other selectable elements outside the dialog. I can't quite see how they are doing it. Can someone please explain?

Comment: It seems to be an `<iframe>` (Edit: ah, no, it's more complicated than that. Not sure how they do it.)

Comment: They used javascript and binding on the keydown event to manage tabbing, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I found that this behaviour is controlled by javascript. jqueryui binds to the keydown event in dialogs:

```
    this._on( this.uiDialog, {
        keydown: function( event ) {
            if ( this.options.closeOnEscape && !event.isDefaultPrevented() && event.keyCode &&
                    event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.close( event );
                return;
            }

            // prevent tabbing out of dialogs
            if ( event.keyCode !== $.ui.keyCode.TAB ) {
                return;
            }
            var tabbables = this.uiDialog.find(":tabbable"),
                first = tabbables.filter(":first"),
                last  = tabbables.filter(":last");

            if ( ( event.target === last[0] || event.target === this.uiDialog[0] ) && !event.shiftKey ) {
                first.focus( 1 );
                event.preventDefault();
            } else if ( ( event.target === first[0] || event.target === this.uiDialog[0] ) && event.shiftKey ) {
                last.focus( 1 );
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        },
```

Basically, this allows looping around in the dialog by the tab key.